# VPC subnets don't support /30?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

According to the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html): "The first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are not available for you to use..."

So this means VPCs dont support point to point subnets right? I tried creating a /30 subnet to test and it would not let me so Im guessing this is why, but want to confirm.

Comment: What would be the purpose of a "point to point" subnet in a VPC?  It sounds as if maybe you're trying to solve a problem that you haven't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct. AWS reserves those IP addresses for their own use (DNS resolvers, Internet Gateways, etc.), and because of this, they enforce a minimum subnet size.